# How to run an xpath over html page in python?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I think using lxml library in python can help, but not able to find out how to do this??

Comment: Is it an xhtml page? Because not all html  is valid xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple starting point...

```
import lxml.html
page = lxml.html.parse('http://www.google.com').getroot()
print page.xpath('//a/@href')
```